# How can I eliminate duplicates using MAX function?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables

`recommendation_object_id`, `exhibitor_name`, `event_edition_id`, `timestamp`

I want to hide/remove the duplicates in **recommendation_object_id** to make it a primary key.

I successfully removed most of the dups, but a few recommendation id's have a different event edition id so some id's are still duplicating as a result.

A colleague of mine said I could eliminate those further by using max(timestamp) but I could not pull it off :(

My current query is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.recommended_object_id, ed.exhibitor_name, sd.event_edition_id, r.object_type, max(r.timestamp)
FROM recommendations r
left join show_details sd on r.event_edition_id = sd.event_edition_id
left join exhibitor_details ed on r.recommended_object_id = ed.exhibitor_id
group by r.recommended_object_id, ed.exhibitor_name, sd.event_edition_id, r.object_type
order by r.recommended_object_id
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

If you want one row per `recommended_object_id`, the one with the most recent timestamp, then use window functions:

```
select r.*
from (select r.recommended_object_id, ed.exhibitor_name, sd.event_edition_id, r.object_type, 
           row_number() over (partition by recommended_object_id order by r.timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from recommendations r left join
           show_details sd
           on r.event_edition_id = sd.event_edition_id left join 
           exhibitor_details ed
           on r.recommended_object_id = ed.exhibitor_id
     ) r
where seqnum = 1
order by r.recommended_object_id;
```